# One of my baby chicks looks like it is going to die...what should I do?

Tags: behavior, health, eating, birds, chickens

I have 10 chicks. They are all hens. But one of them is weak and is always sleeping under the food and doesn't eat like the others. What should I do? I would hate to see her die so soon... Please help!

Comment: You will have to intervene. Nature is [red in tooth and claw](https://interestingliterature.com/2016/01/a-short-analysis-of-canto-lvi-from-tennysons-in-memoriam/), and the fittest survive. It is not at all unusual for the weakest member of a clutch or litter to be a "runt". Sorry about that.

Comment: Hi Gabbie and welcome to Pets, please create an account on Pets SE if you want to be able to reply to comments, etc.

Comment: I appreciate your sympathy, Weather Vane. Thank you, lila too.

Comment: When you are in concern of the health of your chick, then you should see a vet. Do not wait for the guesses of "strangers from the internet" ;) If the chick is healthy and it is the behavior of the others you are concerned by, then this is the right place for this question :)

Comment: My chick (same one) looks stronger now and she is looking great and healthy. Thanks to all of you for your help.

Comment: Hey Gabbie thanks for coming back to us and posting an update ^.^ if you would like, you could elaborate a little with some details and post an answer to your own question, so that we could reward you with reputation for this. Answers need to be longer and more detailed than comments, so if you decide you want to post one then you could include: what you've done through this period of time, how was the chick's behavior changing over time, etc. in essence just that it would be useful if someone in the future has a similar problem. I'm happy it turned out well for your chicken.

Comment: Thank you lila, I saw that my other chicks were kind of pushing her around and stepping on her and she is weak and she can't get up as easily, and I saw it and I took her by herself and let her roam around the grass and eat bugs and shoots that were growing in my backyard, and she got stronger after only 2 days, and now is she with the other chicks, looking healthy and happy. :)